Python Memory profiler not showing the profiling for garbage collection
I have a FastAPI service, when deployed it uses minimal RAM of 600MB approx, but after a few days, the RAM consumption is going to 5GB and doesn't come down.
So I am trying to profile my code. I added memory-profiler to the middleware. I could see the consumption, but it never goes down at the end of the execution ie., I couldn't see any decrements in the memory consumption output from the profiler.
When the continuous calls are made, I could see that the next call is starting with the memory that is consumed at the end of the previous call.
I was expecting garbage collector to freeup some memory before the next call. Why isn't the memory freed up?
Is this expected?
Call 1

Call 2

Call 3


Did you find any solution to this?

@RishabhSagar No. Couldn't find any.
